# Serial Connection on Win 10 IOT

Tags: pi-2, serial, windows-iot

With the new insider preview win 10 iot 10556 the serial port from raspberry pi2 is now available. I want to test it but my SerialDevice is always NULL. Here is my code:

```
private SerialDevice serialPort = null;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    InitSerial();
}

private async void InitSerial()
{
    string portName = "UART0";

    string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(portName);

    var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs, null);

    if (myDevices.Count == 0)
    {
        Status.Text = "Device not found...";
        return;
    }

    SerialDevice device = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);

    Status.Text = device.PortName;

}
```

Does somebody try it with success? Where is my failure?

Comment: did you have a look at this page? https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is the answer for the problem. I have to add these lines to the Package.appxmanifest file.

```
<Capabilities>
  <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
    <Device Id="any">
      <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
    </Device>
  </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

Now the serial connection with the on board Rx/TX Pins works fine.